# Is it possible to access the current record id in the LifecycleHandler of a Canvas app that is embedded in a page layout?

Tags: canvas, canvaslifecyclehandler

I am attempting to get the context of the record being viewed, within a [`CanvasLifecycleHandler`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_canvas_CanvasLifecycleHandler.htm) class so that I can perform some work and enrich the parameters collection in the Canvas Signed Request with additional data related to the current record.

The [EnvironmentContext](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_canvas_EnvironmentContext_methods.htm) makes it trivial to retrieve the parameters values and update them for my use case but it appears that it is not possible within the `onRender()` method to retrieve the `id` of the context record.

The only two options I have seen as viable solutions for passing the current record id into the context of the `onRender()` method require either the usage of the `<apex:canvasApp parameters="{p1: 'value1', p2: 'value2'}"/>` tag or a Chatter canvas feed item by using the `parameters` variable when creating the feed item. [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/parameters_object.htm)

Unfortunately, when you [embed a canvas app directly into a layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/add_canvas_app_to_page_layout.htm) it appears that there is no mechanism in place to allow for specifying data to add to the parameters collection.

1. Is this true?
2. Are my only two workarounds to either:

   - use the CSR content to call back to Salesforce from the remote app for the additional data or
   - completely disallow my canvas app from being able to be embedded directly into layouts without being wrapped in a VF page?